# Syntax Error: Identifier (Error C2061)

Tags: c++

I hate to post something so subtle, but this has me completely stumped on what I am doing wrong:
When I compile, it's not liking Class Simulator at all. I get the error

```
syntax error : identifier 'Simulator'
```

at every instance of Simulator I use inside the DOCO header file. It also does this for my Pellet struct. The code was working completely fine until I started adding functions that work with the Simulator class inside DOCO.h.
The Simulator class uses the DOCO struct and the DOCO struct is using class Simulator. Is that a problem? Maybe I used included my headers wrong?

Here is a link to the error I get if it helps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yha416c7.aspx

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Simulator.h"   //<---Has a chain of includes for other header files
int main()
{
    RandomNumberGen R;
    Simulator S;
    Pellet P;
    DOCO D;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Header Files:
Simulator.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Pellet.h"
#include "DataParser.h"
#include "DOCO.h"
#include "RandomNumberGen.h"
#include "Cell.h"
#include "Timer.h"

using namespace std;

class Simulator
{
private:
    int s_iDocoTotal;
    int s_iPelletTotal;
    int s_iGridXComponent;
    int s_iGridYComponent;
    int tempX;
    int tempY;

    //Pellet P;
    //DOCO D;


    static const unsigned int s_iNumOfDir=8;


public:
    Simulator();
    ~Simulator();

    //int GenerateDirection();
    void InitiateDOCO(RandomNumberGen *R, DOCO *D, vector<DOCO>&);  //
    void SpreadFood(RandomNumberGen *R, Pellet *P, vector<Pellet>&, const int x, const int y);      //
    void AddPellet(Pellet *P, RandomNumberGen *R);          //
    void CheckClipping(Pellet *P, RandomNumberGen *R);      //
    void CheckPellets(Pellet *P, RandomNumberGen *R);       //
    void CreateGrid(int x, int y);//
    int GetGridXComponent();    //
    int GetGridYComponent();    //
    int GetDocoTotal();
    vector<DOCO> docoList;                  //Holds the Doco coordinates
    vector<Pellet> pelletList;              //!!Dont use this!! For data import only
    vector<vector<int> > pelletGrid;    //Holds X-Y and pellet count
    char **dataGrid;        //Actual array that shows where units are

    Simulator(const int x, const int y) : 
                s_iGridXComponent(x), 
                s_iGridYComponent(y),
                pelletGrid(x, vector<int>(y)){}
};
```

DOCO.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include "Simulator.h"
//#include "DataParser.h"



using namespace std;

struct DOCO
{
private:
    int d_iXLocation;
    int d_iYLocation;
    int d_iEnergy;
    int d_iMovement;
    int d_iTemp;
    //Simulator S;
    //RandomNumberGen R;
    //Pellet P;
    enum Direction { NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, NORTHWEST, NORTHEAST, SOUTHWEST, SOUTHEAST};


public:
    DOCO();
    ~DOCO();
    //int a is the position in docoList to reference DOCO
    int GoNorth(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoSouth(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoEast(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoWest(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoNorthWest(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoNorthEast(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoSouthWest(Simulator *S, int a);
    int GoSouthEast(Simulator *S, int a);

    //int a is the position in docoList to reference DOCO
    void Sniff(Simulator *S, RandomNumberGen *R, int a);        //Detects DOCOs and food
    void Reroute(Simulator *S, RandomNumberGen *R, int a);  //Changes DOCO direction
    void SetDOCO(int tempX, int tempY, int tempEnergy, int tempMovement);
    int GetEnergy();    //
    int SetEnergy();
    int SetMovement();
    int GetMovement();  //
    int GetXLocation(); //
    int GetYLocation(); //
    void SetXLocation(int d_iTemp);
    void SetYLocation(int d_iTemp);
    void EatPellet(Pellet *P, Simulator *S, int a);//ADD DOCO ARGUMENT / DONT OVERLAP DOCO AND PELLETS
    void MoveDoco(Simulator *S, int a);
    void Death();
};
```

Comment: are you including these headerfiles in the main.cpp ?

Comment: Nice with run and copy, how did you do that?

Comment: I see a main() function with no `#include`s.  So of course the compiler will complain when you introduce something such as `Simulator` out of the blue like that.  Also, there is no need to repeat the `class` and `struct` keywords when creating an instance.

Comment: @Surt: Looks like the `<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->` and `<!-- end snippet -->` surrounding the snippets enable that (you can see them if you edit the post).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste in my #include with the main(). Post is edited. And with removal of class and struct keywords in the main(), I still have the same error. Thanks

Comment: @AbductedMonkey `The Simulator class uses the DOCO struct and the DOCO struct is using class Simulator. Is that a problem?`  You have a recursive inclusion.  Simulator needs to know what a DOCO is, but DOCO needs to know what a Simulator is, and around and around we go...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie So since the Simulator class is using the DOCO object, I'm not allowed to use Simulator class inside DOCO? This puts a huge damper on how I programmed this..

Comment: @AbductedMonkey - See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my comment above suggested, your problem has to do with recursive inclusion.

You can do one of two things:

1) Change your Simulator class so that you use references to DOCO or pointers to DOCO, and thus `forward declare` DOCO.

2) Change your DOCO header to use pointers to Simulator or references to Simulator, and then just forward declare `Simulator`.

The easiest one to change (if those comments in your code remain) is to change `DOCO.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

class Simulator;

struct DOCO
{
...
};
```

Inside of the `DOCO` struct definition, you can specify references and pointers to `Simulator`, not Simulator objects.

I also advise to *not* put `using namespace std;` in a header file.  This is discussed in many threads here on SO as to why you shouldn't have that line in your header file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you didn't mean to forward declare the classes.

```css
int main()
{
 RandomNumberGen R;
 Simulator S;
 Pellet P;
 DOCO D;
  
    system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given a visible class `RandomNumberGen`, it's perfectly legal to refer to the type as `class RandomNumberGen`. The problem is that (assuming that's the entire source file) the class names aren't visible. Removing the `class` and `struct` keywords will merely change the error message.

Comment: Even on removal of the keywords struct and class in the main(), I have the error. As far as visibility, the other source files are pointing back to the struct (or class) when used. For example: void CheckClipping(Pellet *P, RandomNumberGen *R);

Comment: @AbductedMonkey As my comment above suggested, your problem has to do with recursive inclusion.  You need to change your Simulator class so that you use references to DOCO or pointers to DOCO, and thus `forward declare` DOCO.

Comment: I just noticed that the code in the question actually has several `#include` directives. You didn't include them in the snippet in your answer, and I assumed that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After your #includes in your `Simulator.h` file, add the line

```
struct DOCO;
```

After the #includes in your `Doco.h` file, add the line

```
class Simulator;
```

This tells your compiler that even though while compiling the Simulator file it doesn't yet know what a DOCO is, it well eventually figure that out. Likewise for compiling the DOCO file.

When you forward-declare a class like this, you are not able to create any instances of that class until the class has been defined. You can, however, create pointers or references to that class. So if your DOCO struct needs to have a Simulator and vice-versa, make them contain pointer members rather than object members.